# WebLogic Jax-ws web service error: ClusterRoutingTubeUtils not ready

Tags: soap, weblogic, jax-ws

I'm trying to create a SOAP web service using Oracle WebLogic 10.3.4 and jax-ws api.

For now, i'm trying to test a simple example:

```
package HelloService.hello;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService
public interface HelloWorld {

    @WebMethod
    public String getHelloWorld(@WebParam(name = "str") String input);
}
```

---

```
package HelloService.hello;

import javax.jws.WebParam;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@WebService(endpointInterface = "HelloService.hello.HelloWorld")
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld {

    public String getHelloWorld(@WebParam(name = "str") String input) {
        return "Hello World message: " + input;
    }

}
```

In my WebLogic installation, I have a cluster and a server in it, where I deploy this web service. After being deployed, I can access the wsdl file without any problem, but when I send a request to the web service i get the following exception instead of the expected response (I'm testing the web service with SoapUI plugin for Eclipse):

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>ClusterRoutingTubeUtils weblogic.wsee.jaxws.cluster.ClusterRoutingTubeUtils@782d8a2f not ready, no WseeClusterRoutingRuntimeMBean/WseeRuntimeMBean</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:exception class="java.lang.IllegalStateException" note="To disable this feature, set com.sun.xml.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.disableCaptureStackTrace system property to false" xmlns:ns2="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/">
               <message>ClusterRoutingTubeUtils weblogic.wsee.jaxws.cluster.ClusterRoutingTubeUtils@782d8a2f not ready, no WseeClusterRoutingRuntimeMBean/WseeRuntimeMBean</message>
               <ns2:stackTrace>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.cluster.ClusterRoutingTubeUtils" file="ClusterRoutingTubeUtils.java" line="87" method="ensureSOAPRouter"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.cluster.ClusterRoutingTubeUtils" file="ClusterRoutingTubeUtils.java" line="95" method="handleInboundMessage"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.wsee.jaxws.cluster.ClusterRoutingServerTube" file="ClusterRoutingServerTube.java" line="70" method="processRequest"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="866" method="__doRun"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="815" method="_doRun"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="778" method="doRun"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.api.pipe.Fiber" file="Fiber.java" line="680" method="runSync"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.server.WSEndpointImpl$2" file="WSEndpointImpl.java" line="403" method="process"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="532" method="handle"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter" file="HttpAdapter.java" line="253" method="handle"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter" file="ServletAdapter.java" line="140" method="handle"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="129" method="doGet"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate" file="WSServletDelegate.java" line="160" method="doPost"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet" file="WSServlet.java" line="75" method="doPost"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="727" method="service"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet" file="HttpServlet.java" line="820" method="service"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction" file="StubSecurityHelper.java" line="227" method="run"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper" file="StubSecurityHelper.java" line="125" method="invokeServlet"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl" file="ServletStubImpl.java" line="300" method="execute"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl" file="ServletStubImpl.java" line="183" method="execute"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="3717" method="wrapRun"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="3681" method="run"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject" file="AuthenticatedSubject.java" line="321" method="doAs"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager" file="SecurityManager.java" line="120" method="runAs"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="2277" method="securedExecute"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext" file="WebAppServletContext.java" line="2183" method="execute"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl" file="ServletRequestImpl.java" line="1454" method="run"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.work.ExecuteThread" file="ExecuteThread.java" line="207" method="execute"/>
                  <ns2:frame class="weblogic.work.ExecuteThread" file="ExecuteThread.java" line="176" method="run"/>
               </ns2:stackTrace>
            </ns2:exception>
         </detail>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

I've searched in google that some WebLogic versions have this issue when deploying a web service in a cluster. There is a fix but i can't apply it. IS there any workaround? Is this a common situation?

What alternatives do I have to develop a SOAP web service with WebLogic?

Thks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue. We applied the weblogic patch to resolve this issue and things began to work. Jax ws at times fails to work in clustered env, you can try to directly point to the deployed server url to make things work.

We are still facing the problem in http server to websphere as well. We pointed directly to the webphere deployed location to make things work.